# Unable to serialize/ de-serialize complex Python Object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to serialize a python object with pickle https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html , but unable to do so. It throws error "Maximum recursion level reached". I tried to set the recursion level with below code. But it doesn't help.
sys.setrecursionlimit(16384)

I googled and found put if your object is complex and have DataFrame, functions with yields, nested functions, lambdas, frame, generator, traceback, pandas etc its quite difficult to serialize and de-serialize.

I also tried to use other popular python libraries which claims that they address this issue but with no luck.

https://pypi.org/project/dill/0.3.0/#description
https://pypi.org/project/yccloudpickle/#description

Any suggestions and pointers are most welcome.

Thanks,
Ajeet

Comment: Could you please provide the code that you use to serialize and the code of your class ?

Comment: 1- ser = pickle.dumps(item), 2- deser = pickle.loads(ser) Its crashing while de-serializing and error is "Maximum recursion level reached"